# How can I disable SyncNoButtons.wmv

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Dell laptop with a Synaptics touchpad. After installing the Synaptics driver for some of the additional functionality it provides, I started seeing a weird problem. Tapping my touchpad in some part, I'm not even sure where, caused a short video to pop up in VLC. The video is called SyncNoButtons.wmv. I don't know what it is or where it came from, but it is definitely tied to the Synaptics stuff.

How can I stop this annoying video from playing when I'm trying to use my touchpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Synaptics enables what it calls "Tap Zones" on your touchpad. And slightly more annoyingly, they enable running "SyncNoButtons.wmv" whenever you tap the upper-right of the screen.

Here's how to disable it:

1) Open Mouse settings and go to the page for the Synaptics touchpad. Click Settings

[image: Mouse settings]

2) Click the gears to the right of `Tapping`. If you have tapping disabled, you'll have to temporarily check the box so you can get into those settings.

[image: Synaptics settings - Tapping]

3) For the `Top Right Action`, select some other action. If you don't want these "zones" enabled, you can either uncheck the box that says `Enable Tap Zones`, or simply change that action.

[image: Tap Zones settings]